# Find employee tenure for a company

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written the following query to get the employees tenure yearwise.

Ie. grouped by "less than 1 year", "1-2 years", "2-3 years" and "greater than 3 years".

To get this, I compare with employee staffed `end_date`.

But I am not able to get the correct result when comparing with staffed `end_date`.

I have pasted the complete code below, but the count I am getting is not correct.

Some employee who worked for more than 2 years is falling under <1 year column.

```
    DECLARE @Project_Id Varchar(10)='ITS-004275';

With Cte_Dates(Period,End_date,Start_date,Project_Id)
As
(
SELECT '<1 Year' AS Period, GETDATE() AS End_Date,DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()) AS Start_date,@Project_Id AS Project_Id
UNION
SELECT '1-2 Years', DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE()),DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE()),@Project_Id
UNION
SELECT '2-3 Years', DATEADD(YY,-2,GETDATE()),DATEADD(YY,-3,GETDATE()),@Project_Id
UNION
SELECT '>3 Years', DATEADD(YY,-3,GETDATE()),'',@Project_Id
),

--select * from Cte_Dates
--ORDER BY Start_date DESC


Cte_Staffing(PROJECT_ID,EMP_ID,END_DATE) AS
(
SELECT FK_Project_ID,EMP_ID,MAX(End_Date)AS END_DATE FROM DP_Project_Staffing
WHERE FK_Project_ID=@Project_Id
GROUP BY FK_Project_ID,Emp_ID
)



SELECT D.PROJECT_ID,D.Start_date,D.End_date,COUNT(S.EMP_ID) AS Count,D.Period
FROM Cte_Staffing S
RIGHT JOIN Cte_Dates D
ON D.Project_Id=S.PROJECT_ID
AND S.END_DATE<D.End_date AND S.END_DATE>D.Start_date
GROUP BY D.PROJECT_ID,D.Start_date,D.End_date,D.Period
```

Comment: i need based on the current date, give me the start_date and end_date for following terms:- <1 year,1-2 year,2-3 year,<3 year

Comment: I'd make >3 years NULL rather than '' and use that in your where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT FK_Project_ID,E.Emp_ID,MIN(Start_Date) AS Emp_Start_Date ,MAX(End_Date) AS Emp_End_Date,
    E.Competency,E.First_Name+' '+E.Last_Name+' ('+E.Emp_Id+')' as Name,'Period'=
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(Start_Date),MAX(End_Date))<=12 THEN '<1 Year'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(Start_Date),MAX(End_Date))>12 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(Start_Date),MAX(End_Date))<=24 THEN '1-2 Years'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(Start_Date),MAX(End_Date))>24 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(Start_Date),MAX(End_Date))<=36 THEN '2-3 Years'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(Start_Date),MAX(End_Date))>36 THEN '>3 Years'
        ELSE 'NA'
        END  
    FROM DP_Project_Staffing PS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_Ext_Emp_Master E 
        ON E.Emp_Id=PS.Emp_ID
    WHERE FK_Project_ID=@PROJ_ID
    GROUP BY FK_Project_ID,E.Emp_ID,E.Competency,First_Name,Last_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

i think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186819.aspx) will solve the problem

as you can see, you should use is like this:

```
DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

you should also get the `GETDATE()` to a parameter

Comment: Thanks Liran...but i need the exact query

Comment: i am not able to figure out

Comment: i have already used dateadd function, the way you are suggesting

Comment: but not getting the result

Answer (score 0):

I find your query logic a little bit messy. Why don't you just compute the total period for every employee and use CASE clause? I can help you with code if you'll give me DP_Project_Staffing table structure. Do you have begin_date field in it?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the `MAX(End_date)` of the CTE staffing table. In that case, when an employee has several entries, only the most recent will apply. You want to use `MIN` instead.

Like this:

```
Cte_Staffing(PROJECT_ID,EMP_ID,END_DATE) AS
(
SELECT FK_Project_ID, EMP_ID, MIN(End_Date)AS END_DATE 
  FROM DP_Project_Staffing
...
```

Re-reading your question, you probably don't want the staffing `end_date` for tenure calculation; you'd want to use the `start_date`. (Or whatever the column is called in `DP_Project_Staffing`)

I would also change the `WHERE`/`JOIN` clause to be inclusive on one of the sides, so you have either

```
AND S.END_DATE <= D.End_date AND S.END_DATE > D.Start_date
```

or

```
AND S.END_DATE < D.End_date AND S.END_DATE >= D.Start_date
```

Since you are using miliseconds in the date-comparison it won't make any difference in this case. However, should you change the granularity to be only the date, which would make more sense, you would lose all records where the employee started exactly 1 year, 2 years, etc. ago.